# Best way to share a single class dependency in Java

Tags: java, maven, version-control

I often make many Java projects to deal with parsing and string manipulation. Since the native String class from Java is a bit limited for these cases, I always end up creating an utility class to manipulate Strings.

However, copying and pasting the same (or almost the same) class in every project is a hassle. So I'm planning to make a single version of this and share as a dependency between projects. The only way to do this that I know of is versioning a maven project in git and importing it as a jar in other maven projects. But is there a simpler solution?

Creating a separate repository and packaging a single class into a jar seems a bit of an overhead. Plus, some simple non-maven projects would have to create a pom.xml just to download this class. So I wonder, is there any other tool to share simple dependencies for small projects? What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: You need to create a new procect with package structure that includes your file and export it as jar. How you include this jar is up to you. You could just simply add it as dependency if you don't want to use maven and version-control. If you do want to use these tools there is no fast workaround, since they are not optimized for single class usecases.

Comment: Your IDE may allow you to include other projects as a library (i.e., projects in the IDE, not necessarily full externally produced projects), and it may allow you to specify whether to keep that project external or just copy it into the final build.  Which IDE do you use?

Comment: No it's not an overhead. It's a clean separation of concern. Make a separate project which contains the class you would like and also including the unit tests in there. This offers the opportunity to make separate releases over the time bases on improvements or issues/bugs etc. Also using a Maven project and deploying it to a repository (for example central repository) opens an easy way for others to consume that...and resuse this...

Comment: The amount of footwork to make a maven artifact in a repository available to others is considerably more than copy pasting a single class.  Good exercise though. 

Question is what you actually have as it fits in a single class. Are you sure that Java 17 doesn’t provide something close enough  out of the box for most of it? Text blocks gave a lot.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I agree that just copying and pasting is usually more simple. But if you do it in 10 projects and then decides to change something, it gets annoying. Regarding this utility class, I love Java but there are some things that could be easier in String, like getting substring by text (not indexes), counting substring occurrences and etc. Simple things, but not that simple since we always end up wrapping them in private methods.

Comment: @Leandro86 Yes.  I understand that you have reached the point we all do eventually.  What I'm saying is that 1) creating Maven artifacts _properly_ requires more effort than you think it does (locally hosted repository -> push new versions -> etc, or even Maven Central) and 2) that many of your current helper methods may have simple, well-known alternatives in recent versions of Java.  "substring by texts" sound like a regular expression, "count substring occurrences" like a stream with a suitable collector, and more.   Or perhaps even just know your Guava or Apache Commons libraries.

Comment: @Leandro86 In other words, I am suggesting taking a step back and _code reviewing_ your helper class to see if it is actually needed, or your code perhaps would benefit from knowing your libraries.   Note that this is if you do it for a living, if it is just hobby project then you learn from it, and then by all means go ahead.